# Jquery slideToggle not working completely

Tags: jquery, click, toggle

I am new to jquery and javascript but am practising by doing. I would like to create a simple click function where content below is revealed. Simple stuff you say. For some reason it is not in my case. I have an example at http://jsfiddle.net/richlewis14/FRP3R/1/.

What I want to do is click on the h3 element and then it will reveal all the content underneath. What I would also like to do is not use the slideUp function to hide the content first as when loading the page you can see the content disappear, which looks a little tacky to me. Do I need to hide the div rather than slideUp on load?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="span4">
      <div class="widget">
        <div class="widget-header">
          <i class="icon-info-sign icon-large"></i>
           <h3 class="clickme">Core</h3>
        </div><!--/widgetheader-->
         <div class="widget-content-box">
          <p>Hello</p>


         </div><!--/widget content-->
        </div><!--widget-->
      </div><!--span4--><div class="container">
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".widget-content-box > p").slideUp();
$("h3.clickme").click(function(){
    $(this).next.slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Any help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your code `next` should be `next()`. also note that you should first use `parent()` and then `next()` method(*'.widget-content-box' is not the next sibling of your h3 element*) and when you hide the p element `.widget-content-box` has nothing visible to show, you should hide the `.widget-content-box` instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".widget-content-box").slideUp(); // $(".widget-content-box").hide()
    $("h3.clickme").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().next().slideToggle("slow");
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qxnjj/

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer and explanation, will make a note of this

Answer (score 1):

this is changed jquery:

```
$("h3.clickme").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle("slow");
  });
```

and in css i have added display:none so you dont have to slideUp this div in the first place:

```
.widget-content-box{
border:none;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
background:white;
**display:none;**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two functions here.

You can try to do:

```
$('h3').click(function()
{
   $('.contentBelowH3').slideToggle();
});
```

And you can slide up and down manual by using the same function, but manual toggle.

```
$('h3').click(function()
{
if($('.contentBelowH3').visible())
    {
      $('.contentBelowH3').slideUp();
    }
else
    {
    $('.contentBelowH3').slidDown();
    }
});
```